# Looking for a more efficient way to implement scalar multiplication for word2vec

Tags: python, pytorch, word2vec

I would like to implement myself word2vec in pytorch and the forward method has the following signature:

```
def forward(self, input_index_batch, output_indices_batch):
#input_index_batch - Tensor of ints, shape: (batch_size, )
#output_indices_batch - Tensor if ints, shape: (batch_size, num_negative_samples+1)
```

In the word2vec approach one calculates the dot product between the input in the U - embedding matrix, and each of the num_negative_samples+1 outputs, which correspond to the context words, and the first one is the positive context word, and all remaining - the negative. I have tackled the problem with the following way:

```
    U_batch = self.input.weight.T[input_index_batch]
    for i, output_index in enumerate(output_indices_batch.T):
        V_batch = self.output.weight[output_index]
        dot_prod = torch.einsum('bi,bj->b', U_batch, V_batch)
        if i == 0:
            predictions[:, i] = torch.sigmoid(dot_prod)
        else:
            predictions[:, i] = 1 - torch.sigmoid(dot_prod)
            
    return predictions
```

This works correctly, however, rather inefficiently and slow. What would be more robust way to implement this?

In the init method self.input and self.output are defined as (10 - word2vec dim):

```
self.input = nn.Linear(num_tokens, 10, bias=False)
self.output = nn.Linear(10, num_tokens, bias=False)
```

Comment: Isn't `'bi,bj->b'` computing the outer product of each row of `U_batch` with each row of `V_batch` then summing? I'm not involved in NLP so this may be what you want but it seems strange to call this a dot product.

Comment: If I've interpreted your dimensions right then I think you can do `dot_prod = torch.einsum('bi,kbj->bk', self.input.weight.T[input_index_batch], self.output.weight[output_indices_batch.T])` to compute the "dot product" for everything followed by `predictions = torch.cat([torch.sigmoid(dot_prod[:, [0]]), 1 - torch.sigmoid(dot_prod[:, 1:])], dim=1)` to compute the predictions.

Comment: @jodag I call this a dot product, because it is supposed to make a dot product between column in self.input and row in self.output for each batch. It could be also interpreted as  mutipliying the matrices and leaving only the diagonal part, but this multiplication will involve many uneccesary calculations. Thanks, for the suggestion